# Is there a somewhat official or usually accepted classification of math subjects?

Tags: math-history

We have algebra, topology, calculus... but we all know that these are very vague and very general way to classify math. I came up with this question when I first saw ArXiV`s paper's categories and initially thought that was an already good enough way to classify math knowledge but over time I started thinking it was incomplete.

Comment: lol , nice pun ! :D

Comment: No, not calculus: Real Analysis. The closest to an "official" list is https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet/msc/msc2020.html

Comment: A graphical representation of mathematics as a whole is given here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2939721/a-graphical-representation-of-mathematics-as-a-whole

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a classification by the AMS. The list is way too long to be posted here but can be found in https://zbmath.org/static/msc2020.pdf. Please also check this link https://msc2020.org/

Enjoy :)

Answer (score 1):

While I don't think either of the words *official* or *semi-official* are appropriate, you might be interested in the widely used [classification system](https://mathscinet.ams.org/msnhtml/msc2020.pdf) of [Mathematical Reviews](https://www.ams.org/publications/math-reviews/math-reviews). It evolves over time, and was last updated in 2020.